# Java Servlet Static DAO

Tags: java, servlets, static, dao

I've have tried to read about using static or not using static in my web application and wanted to just quickly ask if my implementation is good.

The following is my servlet

```
Integer total = HousingDAO.getTotal(AppUtils.getId(request));
Integer used = HousingDAO.getUsed(AppUtils.getId(request));

request.setAttribute("total", total);
request.setAttribute("used", used);
request.getRequestDispatcher("system/housing.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And this is my DAO

```
public class HousingDAO {

public static Integer getTotal(String id){
    String sql_total = "SELECT count(*) FROM housing " + 
            "WHERE id = :id ";
    try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.getSql2o().open()) {
        return con.createQuery(sql_total).addParameter("id", id).executeScalar(Integer.class);
    }
}

public static Integer getUsed(String id){
    String sql_total = "SELECT count(*) FROM housing " + 
            "WHERE id = :id AND person IS NOT NULL";
    try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.getSql2o().open()) {
        return con.createQuery(sql_total).addParameter("id", id).executeScalar(Integer.class);
    }
}
}
```

So these are static, does it need to not be static, like this?

```
HousingDAO dao = new HousingDAO();
Integer total = dao.getTotal(AppUtils.getId(request));
Integer used = dao.getUsed(AppUtils.getId(request));

request.setAttribute("total", total);
request.setAttribute("used", used);
request.getRequestDispatcher("system/housing.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

With this DAO

```
public class HousingDAO {

public Integer getTotal(String id){
    String sql_total = "SELECT count(*) FROM housing " + 
            "WHERE id = :id ";
    try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.getSql2o().open()) {
        return con.createQuery(sql_total).addParameter("id", id).executeScalar(Integer.class);
    }
}

public Integer getUsed(String id){
    String sql_total = "SELECT count(*) FROM housing " + 
            "WHERE id = :id AND person IS NOT NULL";
    try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.getSql2o().open()) {
        return con.createQuery(sql_total).addParameter("id", id).executeScalar(Integer.class);
    }
}
}
```

Just would like to know if the first is ok, or do I need to do it like the second one?

EDIT

This is the ConnectionManager class

```
public static Sql2o getSql2o(){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        return new Sql2o(PropertiesManager.getProperty("dburl")
                + PropertiesManager.getProperty("dbname"),
        PropertiesManager.getProperty("dbusername"),
        PropertiesManager.getProperty("dbpassword"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are rarely any good reasons for using static methods. It is most often used in utility  classes and classes that in their nature are singletons, like javas System class.

In your case, having a DAO class with static methods is according to me a bad idea. If the methods are static anything they reference has to be static. What if you want to reuse your DAO class to connect to several different databases?

A better approach is to inject all your dependencies in your DAO class, like the static ConnectionManager, and let the application decide how instances are wired together, not the classes themselves.

So the short answer is, use the second solution, but also remove the static access to ConnectionManager.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to clear it up for me though, the first option will not cause thread leaks or have any problems in the long run other than not being able to change databases and not being the best coding standard correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by thread leaks but the methods are thread safe if ConnectionManager is thread safe, i.e ConnectionManager.getSql2o().open() needs to be thread safe.

Comment: I have edited the post with the ConnectionManager class

Comment: So, it's the same thing here. getSql2o() is thread safe if PropertiesManager.getProperty(String) is thread safe. This is one example of why using static like this is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help. So in my case, PropertiesManager is thread safe, so I will not have any problems with this code, it just isn't good coding standards.

Comment: Well, you might not have thread safety issues, but you might get issues like your DAO throwing a null pointer exception if and when getSql2o returns null.

Comment: That would only happen if the PropertiesManager returned null, and that would only happen if I forgot to add the property to the file. So it shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: Maybe not, but if you configure incorrectly or or get an IOException for some other reason it will look like you got a null pointer exception. Might make it harder to debug. I would just throw the IOException and handle it further up.

Comment: This should probably be for another post but could you throw together a quick example of what you mean by inject dependencies and how I would make connection manager not static?